# Reproduce the same behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, slick.js

i'm trying to reproduce the slider on this website using a slick slider but i dont know how to make the button appear on each template element when the element is centered.
the website:  https://app.resumegenius.com/resume-builder/start
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which slider are you using? Can you provide some link for slider.

Comment: I'm using the slick slider: https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/responsive/

Comment: You must pass settings = { dots: true} as props to the slider component.

Comment: that's not really what i wanted, but i figured out how to do it using CSS. ;)